# Facebook Open Graph tags not being grabbed (Grav CMS)

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

Facebook is not picking up open graph meta tags and the debugger responds as if they're not in the source code at all.

Here's the relevant page source (with title and url anonymized)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Page Title" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://page.url/page-name" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

Comment: Your above code seems fine. Have you tried manually submitting the URL to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?

Comment: I have... it lists all the required og tags as missing, including those above. There are no .htaccess redirects based on user agent, no robots.txt and the content is being served by Grav cms (which doesn't take user agent into account when building content as far as I know).

Comment: Give us an actual example URL, otherwise this is just guesswork.

Comment: The default Quark theme blog items don't seem to even have these tags, did you have to add them by hand by editing the theme or is there a plugin or a settings?

Comment: Sorry it's been so long I don't remember which theme was involved or if I needed to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. For posterity: Grav CMS sends a `Content-Encoding: none` header when GZIP is not enabled. Facebook doesn't like this header, it breaks it's libcurl. In the sharing debugger it doesn't report this, it instead says the tags are missing.

The simplest solution of course is to turn on GZIP in Grav config.

Side note: I thought Grav was going to be a quick solution for a family member, the simple interface coupled with it supposedly being developer friendly under the hood appealed to me. Turns out it's developer friendly in the sense that you will encounter problems that will require your developer experience to solve as a result of there being numerous documentation errors, missing basic features and bugs in the plugins required for basic functionality. Also note that Google is not your friend for solving Grav problems as there's surprisingly little community support compared to other popular CMS.

Not saying this to trash Grav, there's a lot about it that's good, the above is just stuff I wish I'd known going in.

Comment: This Gzip and Facebook opengraph problem has been reported on Grav's discourse forum. Head over there for your future problems, or go to Grav's slack channel for quick support.

Answer (score 1):

The Social Meta Link plugin readme now explains the gzip issue, but for me I additionally had to [patch the plugin source code](https://github.com/clemdesign/grav-plugin-social-seo-metatags/issues/13) by hand on the server to strip the internal port number from the og:url meta links because I run a reverse proxy setup.